# Find same text contents in a Excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, find

I have tried different ways to find out the cells with same text content, but failed.
In the picture in A1 and A4, there is a difference in year, for eg., cell A1 the year '1960' is not the same A4. So I can't use the find replace function because, I can't copy the whole text. Is there a way to find exact repeating text content in the rows like A2 & A6?

[image: Excel sheet]

Comment: If you want to check exact match: starting from [B1] =COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1) will return the number of matches related to the current range. anything > 1 shows the duplicates while the first appearance is not marked as double. Changing the first argument to the total lines e.g. A$1:A$30 will also “include” the first appearance as duplicate.

Comment: Have a go with find() or search()

Comment: So you do want to find the same text with different numbers as being identical or not? Confusing explaination tbh.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For text processing, Excel is not a good choice (it's strength is for numbers). I recommend Julia or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

No, in short, there is not. Excel has no partial string match, or longest matching substring function built in as a cell function. The function you need is closely related to the concept of Levenshtein distance and the popular `diff` command-line tool.

You can write your own cell functions using Excel VBA, use a Macro or try to find an Excel add-in to do this.